# excel search for multiple items

Tags: excel, search, logic

I am trying to search for multiple items in a cell. If any of the terms I am looking for is present, I want cell D to display "Laptop", otherwise, display "Desktop". I can get the following to work, with just one term to search for:

=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("blah",A2),"Laptop",""),"Desktop")

But I want to search for the presence of blah, blah2, and blah3. I don't know how to get Excel to search for any of the following terms. (Not all of them mind you, just any of the following.

I did see that there is an or option for the logic.

=OR(first condition, second condition, …, etc.)

I am not sure how to get these two to work together. Any thoughts on how to get them to display "Laptop" if any of the words are present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A2,"*" &{"blah1";"blah2";"blah3"}& "*"))>0,"laptop","desktop")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the combination of OR, IFERROR and SEARCH as you suggest, but I think the simpler construct would be ...

`=IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("value1",A2)),ISERROR(SEARCH("value2",A2))),"Desktop","Laptop")`